# Java TCP socket listener

Tags: java, tcp

I have very simple TCP socket listener. I want to stop receiving data when the character is `null` or `#`.

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("#")){
    tcpData = tcpData + line;
    }
server.close();
```

is not closing the socket as code flows.  The socket closed only when I am closing from Hyperterminal. What I missed ?

Comment: 1. Is the "#" sent by server? 2. Does the server end that line? 3. Does the server close the connection?

Comment: Don't use `readLine` unless you want to read a *line*.

Comment: What can I use instead readline ?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc? There are three other read methods.

Answer (score 1):

Because `readLine()` only returns null at end of stream, which only occurs in TCP sockets when the peer has closed the connection.

... and clearly you are never sending a line consisting of `#` plus a line terminator.

Comment: Remote terminal sending sensor data . For example string as $353323058181636,EV,D,T,567888.9,+12C,FFFFE000#  which $ is start character and # is end of data character. Each packet coming every minute.  In my case when data ends socket need close the socket.

Comment: So you're reading lines but it isn't sending lines. So don't use `readLine()`.