# String comparison not breaking out of a while loop

Tags: java, string, compare

I am trying these lines:

```
private String line;
private final String stopChr= "#";

BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        tcpData = tcpData + line;
        if(line.equals(stopChr)) break;
}
```

Why is the **if** statement not breaking out of the loop when *#* is present?

Comment: Does the last line contain only `#`?

Comment: Can you post InputStream format?

Comment: $353323058181636,EV,D,T,567888.9,+12C,FFFFE000#

Comment: same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888751/java-tcp-socket-listener/33893818#33893818

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the line is not exactly "#" for example it might have a space after it. I suggest you look at what the line is in your debugger or in an editor to see exactly what characters the String has.

Try printing the following to help see what the string is actually.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line.toCharArray());
```

If you have trailing spaces you can drop these with `trim`

```
if (line.trim().equals(stopChar)) break;
```

Comment: String that need to read from line is $353323058181636,EV,D,T,567888.9,+12C,FFFFE000#

Comment: Use `String.contains` instead then.

Comment: `contains` is a bit dangerous as you might have `#` anywhere in a line.  If you mean the line must end with `#` I suggest using `line.endsWith(stopChar)`

Comment: @user1570701 in that case the string is not what you think it is. I suggest you print out each string as you read it.

Answer (score 0):

If the string contains other characters, as in your example input `$353323058181636,EV,D,T,567888.9,+12C,FFFFE000#` (from your comment on @PeterLawrey's answer), use the following instead of `String.equals`:

```
if(line.contains(stopChr)) break;
```

If it specifically *ends with* the stop character, you can alternatively use:

```
if(line.endsWith(stopChr)) break;
```

Comment: I echo PeterLawrey's comment: "in that case the string is not what you think it is. I suggest you print out each string as you read it". What character encoding are you sending the data in, and what character encoding are you reading it in (it would be your JVM's default character encoding).

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working :

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = "";
        String data = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            data += line;
            if (line.contains("#"))
                break;
        }
```

Also, instead of contains() you can use endsWith() to check for end of file.
You make take help.

Answer (score 0):

for getting everything before the #

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = "";
    String data = "";
    while (true)
        {
        line = br.readLine();

        // break if terminated
        if (line==null)
            break;

        // Check : for debugging only
        System.err.println("LINE : "+line);

        // break if #
        if (line.contains("#"))
            {
            // Get first part, part after, we dont care
            int first=line.indexOf('#');
            data+=line.substring(0, first);

            break;
            }

        else
        data += line;

    }
    // See the result
    System.out.println("DATA:"+data);
```

Comment: I tried that too, not breaks.  I am debugging step by step, the execute line stops on         if (line==null) only when I disconnect the terminal.  Then goes to line        if (line.contains("#") 
During the process the execute line not visits        if (line.contains("#") at all.
I can put here all codes , its not much long

Comment: I am having full string without loss and without # 
$353323058181636,EV,D,T,567888.9,+12C,FFFFE000

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. readLine() function need end of string character `<CR>`. Just replacing "#" to "\n" solved the problem. Thanks to all great team.

Answer (score -1):

you will never get null if the inputstream is from socket. Instead, the `readLine()` method  will  block until you get new data.

Comment: [BufferedReader.readLine returns null if the end of stream is reached](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Comment: in order to simulate  data receive case, I am sending the $353323058181636,EV,D,T,567888.9,+12C,FFFFE000# string  from Hercules terminal. After clicking on SEND button  then DISCONNECT button the while loop breaks because the terminal creates null.